# Erlang: How should I test this?

Tags: erlang

I've got an application where I cast a message to a gen_server to start an operation, then I call the gen_server every second to gather intermediate results until the operation completes. In production, it usually takes a couple of minutes, but it's only limited by the input size and I'd like to test hour long operations, too.

I want to always make sure this operation still works by running a test as needed. Ideally, I'd like to run this test multiple times with different inputs, also.

I use eunit right now, but it doesn't seem to have a purpose-built way of exercising this scenario. Does commmon test provide for this? Is there an elegant way of testing this or should I just hack something up? In general, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to systematically test stateful, asynchronous operations in Erlang.

Comment: You haven't shown any code for us to reason about, so we can't really tell you how you might test it.  In general, test something, look at coverage to find something you didn't test, then test that.  Repeat.

Comment: Nonsense. Perhaps *you* can't. Luckily, I've noticed there are several people reading the Erlang tag who are able to usefully answer general questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, common test will do this.

This is a cut down version of the common test suite skeleton that our erlang emacs mode provides (you can use [the normal erlang one](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.el.html) or [erlware one](http://www.erlware.org/tools/erlware-mode/index.html)):

```
-module(junk).

%% Note: This directive should only be used in test suites.
-compile(export_all).

-include("test_server.hrl").

%%
%% set up for the suite...
%%
init_per_suite(Config) ->
    Config.

end_per_suite(_Config) ->
    ok.

%%
%% setup for each case in the suite - can know which test case it is in
init_per_testcase(_TestCase, Config) ->
    Config.

end_per_testcase(_TestCase, _Config) ->
    ok.

%%
%% allows the suite to be programmatically managed
%%
all(doc) ->
    ["Describe the main purpose of this suite"];

all(suite) ->
    [].

%% Test cases starts here.
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
test_case(doc) ->
    ["Describe the main purpose of test case"];

test_case(suite) ->
    [];

test_case(Config) when is_list(Config) ->
    ok.
```

There are 2 basic ways you could do it.

First up start the gen_server in `init_per_suite/1` and then have a large number of atomic tests that act on that long running server and then tear the gen_server down in `end_per_suite/1`. This is the preferred way - your gen_server should be long-running and persistent over many transactions, blah-blah...

The other way is to make a singleton test and start the gen_server with `init_per_testcase/2` and tear it down in `end_per_testcase/2`

Comment: I guess the biggest issue I have is that I need an arbitrary number of test cases. It might take 5, 10, 23 or any number of calls to the gen_server to retrieve all results. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess instead of treating each request for results from the client to the gen_server as a separate test case, I can just recursively call the same test case function. If this is allowed, it should be perfect.

Comment: Actually, an even better solution is to use the repeat-until-successful strategy, and repeat the test (with a 1 second delay) until it gets the final results. Combined with a timetrap, this should be ideal.

Comment: I feel my participation in this thread is somewhat superfluous :) Keep up the good work!

What I would recommend you do is put a loop in the test that repeats until successful, but maybe do a 1 minute, 10 minute and 1 hour test in the suite..

Answer (score 1):

Testing Stateful Asynchronous operations is hard in any language, Erlang or otherwise.

I would actuall recommend using [etap](http://github.com/ngerakines/etap) and have the asynchronous tests run a callback that will then run etap:end_tests()

Since [etap](http://github.com/ngerakines/etap) uses a running test server and it waits for the end_test call you have a little more control for asynchronous tests.

Comment: Wicked! Thanks for building this. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I started it but Nick Gerakines has taken it a long way from it's initial beginnings. He deserves a fair amount of credit as well.